# Flying saucer does not show images in pdf

Tags: java, html, html-to-pdf, flying-saucer

Here I am trying to convert html to pdf but images available in html are not showing in pdf.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.20</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.20</version>
</dependency
```

**html**

```
                <img id="proof" src="$id1" onerror="this.style.display='none'" /> 
                <img id="proof" src="$id2" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
                <img id="proof" src="$id3" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
                <img id="proof" src="$id4" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
                <img id="proof" src="$id5" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
```

I am converting $id1, $id2... etc. to path and adding it to temp file

```
htmlString = htmlString.replace("$id1", "C:\\Users\\abc\\1.jpeg");

File newHtmlFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".html", dir);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newHtmlFile, htmlString, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));


                System.out.println("About to convert html to pdf");
                ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
                renderer.setDocument(newHtmlFile);
                renderer.layout();
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
                System.out.println("Done");
```

html is showing images properly but in pdf images are missing.

Comment: There is no obvious reason for this issue. I don't have a windows to test it, but it works fine on linux. 
`<html>
<body>
<img src="/tmp/JPEG_example_flower.jpg" />
</body>
</html>`

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows. But works fine on macOS

Comment: Maybe, as a workaround you could [embed the file content directly in the HTML using base64 encoded content](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html).